# Java Character.valueOf('x')?

Tags: java, character

I'm just curious, but what's the difference, when calling a method with parameters, between `'x'` and `Character.valueOf('x')` in Java?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`'x'` is a character primitive

`Character.valueOf('x')` returns a `Character` wrapper containing `x`

Related: [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Character.valueOf(char) takes a char and returns a Character wrapper instance representing the same value. Using toString() on that returns a String containing only that single charcter.